# Create NFT with large amount (100k++). Is it possible?

Tags: nft, erc-721, erc-1155

If I want to create NFT (can be both 721 or 1155) and support the 100k amount. Is it doable? Or do I have to change structure of token?

Comment: 100k what? Total supply of NFTs?

Comment: Yes,  totalSupply.

Comment: Then you don't need to worry about this. You're not in charge of the growth of the blockchain state.

Comment: The only thing you need to keep in mind is the fact that the size of the contract code must have maximum [24KB](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not answerable. It was based on a false assumption about the developer's responsibilities.

Comment: Yes, it is doable. It will be quite expensive to create so many tokens.

Comment: @Ismael It might be expensive if all NFTs were mint by 1 person right? But eventually, I think If user is the person who mint the NFT. The gas will not be expensive. Let's say if user want to mint N token => gas cost will be N * cost for changing the state of data.

Comment: If you won't mint all the token at once it shouldn't matter if you have a supply of 1, 10k, 100k, 100M. The cost of deploying a NFT shouldn't dependent on the total supply.